# how to change num of columns at runtime in gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

i need to change num of column in grid view dynamic at runtime...like shown in image...i am new in android and i don't know how to implement that...implementation requires ...in first row there should be two images and then three row in columns.....

[image]

here is my code.....

```
public class List_of_players extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_of_players, container,
            false);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridview.setAdapter(new Customgrid(getActivity()));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}

public class Customgrid extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context m1Context;

    public Customgrid(Context context) {
        super();
        this.m1Context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 9;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) m1Context)
                .getLayoutInflater();
        View customRow1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.players, null);
        return customRow1;
    }

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intnt = new Intent(getActivity(), Players_details.class);
    startActivity(intnt);
}
```

}

this is xml file...

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gray"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >
</GridView>
```

Comment: hello I have also faced the same problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143569/gridview-with-different-number-of-columns-according-to-the-number-of-row. It may be helped ..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible at all. GridView should looks like a grid.
If you want two different rows please use two different layouts for this: LinearLayout or GridView for example.

```
<!--two columns row -->
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

<!--three columns row-->
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

In this case, you can dynamically change every layout content and even rows number.