# Custom grid-view appearance for android

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

### What output I have:

[image]

---

### What I am trying to achieve:(boxes are the images)

[image]

---

**MainActivity .java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
      gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:columnWidth="90dp"
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:gravity="center"
/>
```

**ImageAdapter .java**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private Context mContext;

   // Constructor
   public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
      mContext = c;
   }

   public int getCount() {
      return mThumbIds.length;
   }

   public Object getItem(int position) {
      return null;
   }

   public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
   }

   // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ImageView imageView;
      if (convertView == null) {
      imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
      imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
      imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
      } else {
      imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
      }

      imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
      return imageView;
   }

   // Keep all Images in array
   public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
      R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
      R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
      R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
      R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
      R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
      R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
      R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
      R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
      R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
      R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
      R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
   };
}
```

---

Comment: you may find the answer you need [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143569/gridview-with-different-number-of-columns-according-to-the-number-of-row

Comment: @student that is not a good answer at all, because it dose not recycle the views although for small number of items it is ok.

Comment: I am looking for something where I can use view holder too for recycling  !

Answer (score 0):

that cant be achieved using the default grid view.
a way to do it is to use a custom adapter for listView.

your get view method should look something like:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null)//set the convert view and the viewholder 
    {
    if (position%2==0)
    {//code to inflate a 2 item row
                LayoutInflater inflater = _context.getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.2Item, parent,false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder._item1 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.2_item_1);

                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder._item2 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.2_item_2)
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    holder.set();
    else

    {//code to inflate a 3 item row
                LayoutInflater inflater = _context.getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.3Item, parent,false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder._item1 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.3_item_1);

                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder._item2 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.3_item_2)
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    viewHolder._item3 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.3_item_3)
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();      
            holder.set();
       }
return rowView;
    }
```

there might be a better way performance wise to do what i mentiond (my getView code might not be precise) so take a look at this tutorial:http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

last comment - your arraylist that is used for the images should also change accordinglly so each item in the array will consist of 2 or 3 images

Answer (score 0):

1) Create `ListView`

2) for each row you have a different layout so you must tell the listview to use convertview in a smart way so override below methods of your adapter for example ArrayAdapter:

`getViewTypeCount()`: this ask you for how many different row layout you have, obviously 2 for your case.

`getItemViewType(int position)`: Get the type of View that will be created by getView that means in getView you pass the position to `getItemViewType(position)` and it returns you a number, for example if it is 2 that means you must use layout that have 3 images in a row if it is 2 use other layout.

other step is the same as an ordinary listview.