# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager - Alternating 3 and 2 column rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

Good Morning-

I have a requirement in my project where I need to show the alternate rows using GridLayout manager. i.e; In First row I need to show 2 images and in Second row I need to show 3 Images.

I am using GridLayout manger with recyclerview and below is my code.

```
GridLayoutManager mNewlyAddedManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext,**3**);
mMyTrawelLogsRecycleView.setLayoutManager(mNewlyAddedManager);
MyTrawellogsDetailsAdapter mImageAdapter = newMyTrawellogsDetailsAdapter(mContext, listAddedTour, false);
mMyTrawelLogsRecycleView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(1));
mMyTrawelLogsRecycleView.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);
```

Requirement screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJB1h.png)

My Output image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQqbo.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridView with different number of columns according to the number of row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143569/gridview-with-different-number-of-columns-according-to-the-number-of-row)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143569/gridview-with-different-number-of-columns-according-to-the-number-of-row

Comment: @Adrian Le Roy Devezin, Can I get some thing suing with recyclerview?

Comment: please clarify what you mean @Anuash

Comment: I am excepting something with Recyclerview instead of Tablet layout. i.e; it's with GridLayoutManager

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629963/gridlayoutmanager-with-different-column-count-per-row

Comment: just use setSpanSizeLookup & define the number of columns to be displayed in respective cases.

Answer (score -1):

Use 6 columns and then override getSpanSize

```
@Override
public int getSpanSize(int position) {
    return getSizeForItem(position);
}
```

You will need to make a function the returns the number of columns each item will take up, either 2 or 3.